# How to specify start date in timeseries google-chart

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a nice simple graph displaying the requests per hour from an API. I want to display the req/h for the time range now - 7 days up until now.

For the hours where there is no data available, there isn't an entry in the json-data-file. So they need to be 'filled'.

At the moment the missing hours in-between are `filled` but somehow it seems impossible to let the chart start at now - 7days.

This is the example data, in Google's json-data format:

```
{"cols":[{"id":"tijdstip","label":"Tijdstip","type":"datetime"},{"id":"reqs","label":"reqs\/hour","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,0,0,0)"},{"v":6}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,14,0,0)"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,19,0,0)"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,20,0,0)"},{"v":42}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,21,0,0)"},{"v":18}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,22,0,0)"},{"v":18}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,23,0,0)"},{"v":6}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,11,20,0,0)"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,13,20,0,0)"},{"v":17}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,13,21,0,0)"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,14,13,0,0)"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,16,15,0,0)"},{"v":8}]}]}
```

And this is the options-object: (i'm using the materials-line chart)

```
options = {
    legend: {
        position: 'none'
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: '',
        format: 'd MMM yyyy HH:00',
    },
    series: {
        0: {axis: 'Aantal'}
    },
    axes: {
        y: {
            Aantal: {label: 'req/h'},
           }
    }
};
```

And the chart initiation:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's the problem with *Material* charts...

there are several options that simply do not work

including what is needed to control the axis labels

`hAxis.minValue` -- or -- `hAxis.ticks`

see this issue for more --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

instead, you can use a *Core* chart, with the following option...

`theme: 'material'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: function () {
    var ticksX = [];
    var today = new Date();
    var lastWeek = new Date(today.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
      ticksX.push(new Date(lastWeek.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * i)));
    }
    var options = {
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: '',
        format: 'd MMM yyyy HH:00',
        ticks: ticksX
      },
      theme: 'material',
      vAxis: {
        title: 'req/h'
      }
    };
    var json = {
      "cols":[
        {"id":"tijdstip","label":"Tijdstip","type":"datetime"},
        {"id":"reqs","label":"reqs\/hour","type":"number"}
      ],
      "rows":[
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,0,0,0)"},{"v":6}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,14,0,0)"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,19,0,0)"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,20,0,0)"},{"v":42}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,21,0,0)"},{"v":18}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,22,0,0)"},{"v":18}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,10,23,0,0)"},{"v":6}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,11,20,0,0)"},{"v":2}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,13,20,0,0)"},{"v":17}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,13,21,0,0)"},{"v":23}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,14,13,0,0)"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,11,16,15,0,0)"},{"v":8}]}
      ]
    };
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: It does! I tried those ticks, but i didn't think of the option not being implemented in the material charts.